# Appending and overwriting certain columns of a pandas dataframe at the same time

Tags: python, pandas

it currently appears quite difficult to figure out an efficient proper solution (meaning: no loops) to a problem such as this:
Given a dataframe with this example structure:

```
     T     x    c1    c2
1  11-12   3   'yes' 'yes'
2  12-12   4   'no'  'yes'
3  13-12   4   'no'  'yes'
4  14-12   4   'yes' 'yes'
5  15-12   2   'no'  'no'
6  16-12   4   'yes' 'yes'
```

If I wanted to add 5 new entries for T and x starting with the 4th interval and thus overwrite 3 intervals before actually appending data, how can this be done elegantly?
E.g., if I wanted to add:

```
    T     x
4 14-12   3
5 15-12   3
6 16-12   4
7 17-12   4
8 18-12   2
```

..it should turn out such as this:

```
     T     x    c1    c2
1  11-12   3   'yes' 'yes'
2  12-12   4   'no'  'yes'
3  13-12   4   'no'  'yes'
4  14-12   3   'yes' 'yes'
5  15-12   3   'no'  'no'
6  16-12   4   'yes' 'yes'
7  17-12   4    nan   nan
8  18-12   2    nan   nan
```

Using a .loc to catch the right T section is not possible due to the needed indices not yet existing. I suppose I could split the supplementary data to do .update or .loc on the already existing part and then append the rest.
But that requires a couple of steps, so is there a better and easier option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `combine_first()`

```
df2.set_index('T').combine_first(df.set_index('T')).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
       T     c1     c2  x
0  11-12  'yes'  'yes'  3
1  12-12   'no'  'yes'  4
2  13-12   'no'  'yes'  4
3  14-12  'yes'  'yes'  3
4  15-12   'no'   'no'  3
5  16-12  'yes'  'yes'  4
6  17-12    NaN    NaN  4
7  18-12    NaN    NaN  2
```

Comment: I looked it up and it seems close. However, the documentation said it will only replace null values. In this example I believe the 4,2,4 wouldn't get updated to a 3,3,4 for x in index 4-6 it seems.

Comment: does it match your expected output? I pasted the output below my answer.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I see now. I tried it and it works because in contrast to the examples in the documentation, the order of the dfs is reversed, thus the smaller, supplementary df's values take precedence. Fantastic, that solves it, thank you again.